# mysql not showing all databases

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to list all my databases. But I only return information schema and one other table.. I checked my user settings/privileges in mysql and I have access to everything.. How can I return all databases

here is the code i used:

```
$set = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES;'); 
$dbs = array(); 
while($db = mysql_fetch_row($set)) $dbs[] = $db[0]; echo implode('<br/>', $dbs);
```

Comment: check no of rows before fetch row, stop using mysql_* its deprecated and closed in new versions.

Comment: better option, `select * from information_schema.schemata`.

Comment: Code format tip: please use brackets around your while statement

Comment: "I checked my user settings/privileges in mysql" --- what were they?  Are you running this in PHPMyAdmin?  Via a web server PHP page?

Comment: I know I shud use mysqli..select * still gives the same return.. I access using localhost/phpmyadmin and my global privilleges is  set to all privileges and grant is set to yes my user is root and my host is 127.0.0.1

Comment: when I run this query directly inside phpmyadmin "show databases" it returns all databases.. but if I run from php my count returns 1

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you really should start using mysqli instead of mysql.

This should solve your problem though:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mysql_username", "mysql_password");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$res = mysqli_query($link, "SHOW DATABASES");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    var_dump($row['Database']);
}
```